# LLVM IR basic blocks meaningful names

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I'm trying to have *meaningful names* for the basic blocks in LLVM IR. That is, instead of the name `6` for this loop header, I would like it to be something like: `loop.header.6`. I'm pretty sure previous `llvm/opt` versions had this option, but I can't seem to find it in `llvm-13`. The actual source code for this is probably irrelevant, but given below for completeness

```
$ sed -n "18,23p" main.ll
6:                                                ; preds = %27, %1
  %7 = load i32, i32* %4, align 4
  %8 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  %9 = icmp slt i32 %7, %8
  br i1 %9, label %10, label %30
```

Source code + compilation flags:

```
$ cat ~/main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
bool isPrime(int p) {
    for (int i=2;i<p;i++)
        for (int j=2;j<p;j++)
            if (i*j == p)
                return 0;
    return 1; }
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("%d\n", isPrime(7));
}
$ ./clang -O0 -c -emit-llvm ~/main.cpp -o main.bc
$ ./llvm-dis ./main.bc -o main.ll
```

Comment: `opt` doesn't add or remove names. It uses passes, some of which add suffixes when they e.g. split a block, but it doesn't add/remove names totally. The names you miss come from the compiler, that is, from the code that parses a source language and (perhaps after more gymnastics) generates LLVM IR, clang in this case. You need to look at options for clang, not for opt. I can't answer usefully because I know next to nothing about clang. (It's a nice compiler and seems well written, and I've used it as a cheat sheet sometimes, that's all I can say about clang.)

Comment: I like your use of `sed` BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value names are only added by a frontend (`clang`) if it is compiled in debug mode / with assertions enabled.

Note that the names might become misleading after optimizations, etc.

Comment: You mean that `clang` itself should be compiled in debug mode right?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Right. LLVM + clang. Either in debug or with assertions enabled